# Vertically center div, but also 20px margin Top & Bottom

Tags: css

How would I vertically center a modal window, but also keep a 20px distance from the edges at Top & Bottom?

Here is what I have currently:

```
#colorbox, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:20px; bottom:20px; left:0; z-index:9499;}
```

It creates a 20px margin on top, but none on bottom. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: The position setting of the container has an effect on how absolutely positioned elements behave.  Why don't you make a jsFiddle showing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BZKHq/1/

The HTML:

```
<p>Lorem or whatever makes your ipsum dolorful Lorem or whatever makes your ipsum dolorful Lorem or whatever makes your ipsum dolorful Lorem or whatever makes your ipsum dolorful Lorem or whatever makes your ipsum</p>

<div id="overlay">Lorem ipsum and stuff...</div>
```

The CSS

```
#overlay {
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute;    /* <<<--- The trick starts here ---<<< */
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:20px;    /* <<<--- The trick ends here ---<<< */
    padding:20px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Why not use short-hand: `margin: 20px`?